# pyspark: Using the window() function and compare strings

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have the following test data. With this data, if have to program the following rule in pyspark (data is really big in reality):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = {'date': ['2014-01-01', '2014-01-02', '2014-01-03', '2014-01-04', '2014-01-05', '2014-01-06'],
     'customerid': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3], 'productids': ['A;B', 'D;E', 'H;X', 'P;Q;G', 'S;T;U', 'C;G']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
```

The rule reads:

"For a customerid, there are more than x transactions with one identical product in the basket within y days."

In my example I go back x=2 days and check for at least y=1 matching customerid.
The result should like this is:

```
date      |customerid|result
2014-01-01|1         |0     
2014-01-02|2         |0         
2014-01-03|2         |0         
2014-01-04|3         |0         
2014-01-05|4         |0         
2014-01-06|3         |1
```

For a time window of 2 days, only for 2014-01-06 we have the case that the identical customerid occurs (customerid 3 on 2014-01-04) and there is also one matching product (G).

I know I could use a time window like this:

```
win = Window().partitionBy('customerid').orderBy((F.col('date')).cast("long")).rangeBetween(
        -(2*86400), Window.currentRow)
```

Unfortunately I'm not getting any further at the moment. I also absolutely don't know how to compare the productids, since they are always only available as a long string.

Thank you!

Comment: in your data provided `customerid 3 on 2014-01-04` has `P;Q`. there is no `G` there. Shouldnt it have a `G` there?

Comment: Thank you very much, I have edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for **spark2.4+**( because of **`array_distinct`**). As long as your **`productids`** are separated by **`;`** , we can **`split`** on that separator to create a list. With the **`window`** you already have, we **`collect_list`**, **`flatten`** it, and then see how many **duplicates** we have. The number of duplicates is your desired **`result`**.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window    
df=spark.createDataFrame(data)
w=Window().partitionBy("customerid").orderBy(F.col("date").cast("long")).rangeBetween(-86400*2,0)
df.withColumn("productids", F.split("productids", "\;"))\
  .withColumn("products", F.flatten(F.collect_list("productids").over(w)))\
  .withColumn("result", F.size("products") - F.size(F.array_distinct("products")))\
  .orderBy(F.col("date")).drop("productids","products").show()


+-------------------+----------+------+
|               date|customerid|result|
+-------------------+----------+------+
|2014-01-01 00:00:00|         1|     0|
|2014-01-02 00:00:00|         2|     0|
|2014-01-03 00:00:00|         2|     0|
|2014-01-04 00:00:00|         3|     0|
|2014-01-05 00:00:00|         4|     0|
|2014-01-06 00:00:00|         3|     1|
+-------------------+----------+------+
```

**UPDATE:**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w=Window().partitionBy("customerid").orderBy(F.col("date").cast("long")).rangeBetween(-86400*2,0)
df.withColumn("productids", F.array_distinct(F.split("productids", "\;")))\
  .withColumn("products", F.flatten((F.collect_list("productids").over(w))))\
  .withColumn("result", F.when(F.size("products")!=F.size(F.array_distinct("products")),F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0)))\
  .drop("productids","products").orderBy("date").show()
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! The only problem is: A basket can also contain the same product more than once.

Comment: Meaning if there are `2 Gs in 2014-01-04` then result for `2014-01-04` should be 1, and result for `2014-01-06` should be 3?

Comment: I mean: If there were two G' in 2014-01-06 and no G in 2014-01-04, the rule should not trigger. G occurs two times, but both G's are in the same basket.

Comment: understood. result should only be either 1 or 0 right?

Comment: Right. It should only be one, if the y customerids coincide and there is at least one matching product in the baskets of this customer. Otherwise 0.

Comment: So it is a little confusing. Example: customerid 5,  2014-01-10, with basket ['A;B,C']. I look back x days and find customerid 5 y times. Now is the question: Does any of the y baskets contain product A, B or C. If yes: 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211245/discussion-between-dominik-and-mohammad-murtaza-hashmi).